# using group by, order by and limit in one select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem to work out a way to answer the following query. I am using SQL Developer

I need to find out what were the top ten institutions in terms of total applicants in 2007. Here is what command I have tried:

```
select i.instid, i.instname, i.insttype,sum(f.TotalNumberApplicants)as TotalNumberofApplicants, f.year 
from INSTITUTION_DIM i, FACT f
where i.INSTID = f.INSTID
and year = 2007
order by f.TOTALNUMBERAPPLICANTS
group by i.INSTID,i.INSTNAME,i.INSTTYPE,f.YEAR
limit 10;
```

I keep getting this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 10 Column: 1

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you put the `group by` clause before `order by` ?

Comment: And `limit` isn't valid in Oracle. (12c has a similar mechanism, but different syntax).

Answer (score 5):

There might be some confusion here. Maybe it worth taking some time to clarify that?

Today, *Oracle Corporation* holds both the *[Oracle Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database)* and *[MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)*. Those two products are different database servers. Despite some similarities, the syntax and feature supported by their implementation of SQL are quite different. The way to limit the number of rows returned by a query is one of them.

The confusion is somehow maintained by the fact that its not quite obvious from [some docs on docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/select.html) that they are in fact related to MySQL. Perhaps you fell into that trap?

For sake of completeness, here how you limit rows returned both with Oracle and MySQL:

### Oracle

For Oracle, one way to do it is simply to use the [pseudo-column `ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ....
  GROUP BY ...
  ORDER BY ...
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
-- Yes, you need a subquery here. But Oracle is smart enough
-- to optimize that statement
```

Starting with Oracle 12c, you may use the [`FETCH` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55645) 
<sub>(straight from the doc as I'm not lucky enough to have tested Oracle 12)</sub>

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

### MySQL

MySQL supports the [`LIMIT` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/select.html#idm48005943332464) since at least MySQL 3.23 if I remember it well. Maybe even before? Anyway, that means a very long time ago.

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SELECT syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql_certificate/the_sql_select_statement.htm)

```
SELECT  [DISTINCT | ALL] {* | select_list}
FROM {table_name [alias] | view_name} 
    [{table_name [alias]  | view_name}]...  
[WHERE  condition]
[GROUP BY  condition_list]
[HAVING  condition]
[ORDER BY  {column_name | column_#  [ ASC | DESC ] } .
```

- Your `Order By` clause should be after `group by` clause
- `Join` is recommended over `Cartesian product`

CODE

```
SELECT i.instid, i.instname, i.insttype,SUM(f.TotalNumberApplicants) AS TotalNumberofApplicants, f.year 
FROM INSTITUTION_DIM i
INNER JOIN FACT f ON i.INSTID = f.INSTID
WHERE year = 2007 AND rownum <= 10
GROUP BY i.INSTID,i.INSTNAME,i.INSTTYPE,f.YEAR
ORDER BY f.TOTALNUMBERAPPLICANTS;
```

Comment: That documentation is for MySQL, bot Oracle RDBMS. `LIMIT` is not valid.

Comment: my bad. It was the first link in my google search and in the oracle website. I will update  it.